# Automation Code Management Using JAVA

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, seetest

I am new to Automation and I have started to work on `SeeTest` Automation. I want to know how to make proper classes and methods for automating an Android Application.

My main concern is to know how to arrange test cases in classes and how to arrange code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I would suggest you to start reading about **Page Object Model** - which is a great way to introduction abstraction in your Selenium tests and provides a programmatic way to drive and interact with UI.

Each page of your AUT (Application Under Test) is mapped to a class file in your code and each method within the class file can be treated as a service offered by the PageObject.

A simple example is provided [here](https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/abstracting-selenium-tests-using-page-object-model).

If you like to read about pro's and con's , there is a great [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688809/disadvantages-of-page-object-model-in-selenium) in SO that talks in length about POM. Also you can go through this link in SQA which talks about the same [topic](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/585/what-are-the-trade-offs-of-using-page-objects-instead-of-a-collection-of-functio).

Note : If you want to involve Python, a very good starting tutorial is [here](https://qxf2.com/blog/page-object-model-selenium/). This example takes a mobile apk, so it is be relatable with what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

In any automation plan regardless of language used, you will need to think about the following concerns

- Reusability
- Maintability
- Test Result Reporting and logging
- Cross Browser/Device Testing

I have put a link to my simple test automation example in Java that addresses this [here](https://github.com/Eseoghene/SeleniumATF-JavaMaven)